# how to pass two arrays as argument in couch

Tags: ruby, couchdb

I want to select all devices from Device table, where device.building id includes **building_ids** array and device.device_type includes **device_types** array.

```
Device.by_building_id_and_type.keys(building_ids,device_types)
```

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on using this query in multiple places, you could write a class method in your `Device` model:

```
def self.by_building_id_and_type(building_ids, device_types)
  where(building_id: building_ids, device_type: device_types)
end
```

or for a one-off (assuming you have the two arrays defined):

```
Device.where(building_id: building_ids, device_type: device_types)
```